# Silverlight 4: Binding to a calculation of control properties

Tags: silverlight, binding, properties, silverlight-4.0

What I would like to do is pretty simple. Given textboxes for ItemPrice, Tax and Total, I need the text value for Total to be bound to ItemPrice + Tax and the Tax value to display ItemPrice * taxRate.

Could someone offer a brief explanation as to how this would be accomplished or point me to an appropriate example? I see property binding examples all over the place, but none that show binding to a calculation of the properties of two controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite simply: bind the `Text` property of the `Total` box to another property on your ViewModel, all that property does is have a getter that returns the sum of *ItemPrice* and *Tax*.

You don't need to bind the Total box to any other control. Just make sure that your ViewModel also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and that you also notify that the *Total* property has changed when *ItemPrice* or *Tax* have changed (so that your bound text automatically updates).

Comment: +1: Something that has properties such as `ItemPrice` and `Tax` really ought to be using a ViewModel.  However it may worth mentioning what a ViewModel is since the OP doesn't mention one already in place.